# Anchor tag helper links to API controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm working on a project in 2017 Visual Studio CE utilizing .Net Core 2.0. I created an *API* directory for my Web API Controllers, and a *Controllers* directory for my standard MVC controllers.

I have a *StoresController* in each directory. The one in the *API* directory specifies the Route attribute as `[Route("api/[controller]")]`. The one in the *Controllers* directory does not have a Route attribute; it relies on the default routes set up in *Startup.cs*.

I created the following Delete link on my Edit view using the built-in tag helpers: `<a asp-action="Delete" asp-controller="Stores" asp-route-id="@Model.Id" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>`

For some reason this links to **/api/stores/{id}** instead of **/stores/delete/{id}**. Is there a way to configure the tag helpers to use the  default MVC routes instead of the API routes? Or do I need to rename classes/action names?

---

**Update:** The `Route` attribute has an `Order` parameter that is supposed to affect the priority of the route when resolving requests. Changing this value did not affect the output of the tag helper.

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple routes to your control with an order, and anchor tag helper with use the first one.

```
[Route("[controller]/[action]", Order = 0)] // Same as default routes
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]", Order = 1)] // Your custom route
```

> By default, all defined routes have an Order value of 0 and routes are
>   processed from lowest to highest.

Answer (score 0):

It's late but for me it was the action names in `StoresApiController`. If you scaffold an API Controller using Visual Studio targeting .NET Core 2.2 (it might be the same as 2.0), it will generates actions with names that have `Stores` or `Store` as suffix:

```cs
// this works
public ActionResult GetStores() { ... }
public string GetStore(int id) { ... }
...
```

But I came from .NET Framework and I used to name my API methods without those suffixes:

```cs
// this doesn't work
public ActionResult Get() { ... }
public string Get(int id) { ... }
...
```

I changed all method names to what Visual Studio would generate for me (`GetStores`, `PostStore`, etc). It worked. I'm not sure why. It might be a bug or my little knowledge about routing, but here is [the issue on Github](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/17695).